# Getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named in kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm getting this error when I try to launch a working code from GitHub:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:\Users\Nasser\OneDrive\Bureau\StarEutopia\main.py", line 7, in <module>
     from home_page import Homege
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'home_page'
```

Here is the code :

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from home_page import HomePage

# Resize the window
Window.size = (350, 600)


class FacebookApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.load_all_kv_files()
        return HomePage()

    def load_all_kv_files(self):
        Builder.load_file("home_page.kv")
        Builder.load_file("components/avatar_image.kv")
        Builder.load_file("components/three_buttons.kv")
        Builder.load_file("components/online_friends.kv")
        Builder.load_file("components/story_widget.kv")
        Builder.load_file("components/posts.kv")

    def on_start(self):
        self.root.dispatch("on_enter")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    FacebookApp().run()
```

I tried quick fix :

```
Extract expression into variable ('jls_extract_var')
Extract expression into function ('jls_extract_def')
```

I don't know what to expect, something in indentation or functions calling is the problem, I'm using VSCode by the way.

Comment: What is HomePage ? Where is that file?

Comment: Perhaps this could be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68838849/attributeerror-module-pages-has-no-attribute-home-page

Answer (score 0):

You probably have no file named home_page in the same directory as main.py. If there is a file like that in the github repository download it and put in the same directory as your main.py.